# Is there a way to know the full balance of a BSC wallet?

Tags: google-sheets, cryptocurrency, binance-smart-chain

I'm having fun with the **BSCscan API** on **Google Sheets** and I'd like to know the full balance of a wallet.

By full I mean :

- Not just BNB
- Even the Stacked, Pooled, Farmed tokens

Because I found a way to know the balance of BNB for a specific wallet but I would like to go beyond and get the full value of a wallet to keep my Income Sheet updated !

A personal yieldwatch.com in a way !

Can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it !

I needed to call the API for a wallet and a contract (token). So each call gives me how much value that particular contract (token) worth in the said wallet.

```
https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56&address=0x89e73303049ee32919903c09e8de5629b84f59eb&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

First I entered the wallet address and then the contract (token) adress and it gives me the value in wei, which I convert to BNB, and USD.